# python - await all coroutines in an Iterable

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

Basically, I have a `list[Coroutine[Any, Any, str]]` and I want them to run in parallel and return their values in the same order (as a `list[str]`).

In javascript I would use `Promise.all` to await all the Promises in an array.
How can I recriate this behavior in python?

Comment: Probably you want "asyncio.gather"

Comment: @MichaelButscher It looks like [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=asyncio%20gather#asyncio.gather) does not accept iterables, it accepts each awaitable as a different parameter.

Comment: If "a" is your list of coroutines you can call it as "asyncio.gather(*a)". It is called [iterable unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists).